# check value of element by class and edit value if element exists otherwise add new html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding some elements to the DOM dynamically and and I want to check and edit the value of itemid if it exists before adding new elements by comparing the value of itemid with an id, if the value is equal to the id I want to edit the value of the element by adding 1 to the previous value, if the value is not equal then I want to add a new set of elements. I have the code below but can't get it to work as intended.

```
    $("#topitems").on("click", ".topitems", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var     values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("source"));
            var itemid = values[i].value;


if (document.getElementsByClassName("itemid").length) {
$('.itemid').each(function() {
  var enteredValue = $(this).val();
if(enteredValue) {
  if (parseInt(enteredValue) == itemid) {
  var oldQty = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name=quantity]").val()
  $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name=quantity]").val(parseInt(oldQty)+1)

}

}
else {
  $('#cart_contents').prepend('
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="'+line+'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td style="align: left !important;">'+label+'&nbsp;&nbsp;(stock:'+inventory+')  </td>
    <td>
        <select name="unit_type" id="unit_type" style="'+isdisplay+'" class="show-menu-arrow" data-style="btn-default btn-sm" data-width="auto">
            <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
            <option value="Gr">Gr</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number"  name="quantity"  id="quantity"  value="1" class="quantity form-control input-sm" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input  type="hidden" class="line" name="line"  value="'+line+'">
                <input  type="hidden" name="itemid" class="itemid"  value="'+value+'">
                    <input  type="hidden" name="costpricemarker" id="costpricemarker" value="'+cost_price+'">
                        <input  type="hidden" name="costprice" id="costprice" value="'+cost_price+'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hprice" id="hprice" value="'+price+'">
                                <input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="'+price+'" class="form-control input-sm" tabindex="3">
                                    <input  type="hidden"  name="tax" id="tax" value="'+tax+'" class="form-control input-sm" tabindex="2">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="discounttype" id="discounttype" value="'+discount+'">
                                            <input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="0"  class="form-control input-sm" tabindex="4">
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span id="currlbltotal">
                                                    <? echo $this->config->item('currency_symbol');?>
                                                </span>
                                                <span id="total">'+price+'</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>');  

}

});
}
 else {

  $('#cart_contents').prepend('
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="'+line+'">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="align: left !important;">'+label+'&nbsp;&nbsp;(stock:'+inventory+')  </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select name="unit_type" id="unit_type" style="'+isdisplay+'" class="show-menu-arrow" data-style="btn-default btn-sm" data-width="auto">
                                                    <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
                                                    <option value="Gr">Gr</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="number"  name="quantity"  id="quantity"  value="1" class="quantity form-control input-sm" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input  type="hidden" class="line" name="line"  value="'+line+'">
                                                        <input  type="hidden" name="itemid" class="itemid"  value="'+value+'">
                                                            <input  type="hidden" name="costpricemarker" id="costpricemarker" value="'+cost_price+'">
                                                                <input  type="hidden" name="costprice" id="costprice" value="'+cost_price+'">
                                                                    <input type="hidden" name="hprice" id="hprice" value="'+price+'">
                                                                        <input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="'+price+'" class="form-control input-sm" tabindex="3">
                                                                            <input  type="hidden"  name="tax" id="tax" value="'+tax+'" class="form-control input-sm" tabindex="2">
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <input type="hidden" name="discounttype" id="discounttype" value="'+discount+'">
                                                                                    <input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="0"  class="form-control input-sm" tabindex="4">
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td>
                                                                                        <span id="currlbltotal">
                                                                                            <? echo $this->config->item('currency_symbol');?>
                                                                                        </span>
                                                                                        <span id="total">'+price+'</span>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>');  

}

  });
```

Comment: Why are you using `getElementsByClassName` when you are already taking the hit of loading jQuery on the page?

Comment: what would be the better way to address the issue?

Comment: It's not an issue.  It's a code smell.  Something that doesn't "look right".  Everything that you do as a programmer should be done for a reason.  When a programmer reads logic like that and sees you doing things two different ways, the immediate response is "why?".  To do something like that, you should have a reason, otherwise keeping things consistent means less quesitons asked.

Comment: With regards to your issue, it would be helpful if you could show us an example of the markup that you are working with.  And define where `itemid` is coming from.

Comment: eidted to show ful code, the getElementsByClassName is there because I started on this usnig ony javascript and later added jquery, so I will be removing inconsistency once the code is final

Comment: In `var itemid = values[i].value;` is i set? Does itemid definitely have a value?

Comment: yes it would have a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My jQuery is pretty rusty and I'm not sure I haven't lost some important details of what you're trying to do, but hopefully this is helpful:

```js
const cart_row_string = (item_id) =>
  '<tr>' +
    '<td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" /></td>' +
    '<td><input type="hidden" name="itemid" class="itemid" value="' + item_id + '">' + item_id + '</td>' +
  '</tr>';

const add_item = (item_id) => {
  if(item_id) {
    const $table_body = $('#cart_table_body');
    const $item = $table_body.find('.itemid[value="' + item_id + '"]');

    if($item.length === 0) {
      $table_body.prepend(cart_row_string(item_id));
    } else {
      const $item_row = $item.closest('tr');
      const $quantity = $item_row.find('input[name="quantity"]');
      $quantity.val(parseInt($quantity.val()) + 1);
    }
  }
};

$('#add_button').click(() => add_item(parseInt($('#id').val())));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id" name="id" type="number" />
<button id="add_button">Add</button>
<table id="cart_table">
  <thead><tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Item ID</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody id="cart_table_body"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much, I was able to get it working with just one edit using your code which makes your answer acceptable for me.